# How the Markov Chain Monte Carlo chains can be trusted through diagnostic plots

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, metropolis-hastings

I am given several diagnostic plots of parameter values from a generated MCMC chains. [image]. It is asking me that Do the diagnostic plots suggest that the MCMC chains can be trusted?

My attempt: I tried to find the difference in the diagnostic plots for each parameter. It seems to me the diagnostic plot of parameter aSigma suggests the MCMC cannot be trusted. Because the autocorrelation does not converge/approach to zero as the lag between 0 and 150. Also, the density of aSigma is not normal distributed. Is my attempt sufficient enough or how I can evaluate the MCMC chains can be trusted through diagnostic plots.